# Best way to change UI, working with activity and fragments

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity

So I am trying to integrate Google Maps into my application, I came across a concept that I don't entirely understand. I have seen that adding google maps into an app and it seems the most common way to do so is with an activity.

I found some websites and a SO question showing how to put Google Maps in a fragment, but would that be an issue if the user is constantly clicking on profiles and going back? Causing the map to be recreated or resumed constantly. Would that performance be better if the map was an activity instead?

Basically, Im not sure the best way to transition from an activity GUI to a fragment? I've had an app that only used 1 activity, I just used multiple different fragments changing them with this code

```
FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();
    FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();
    Fragment fragment = getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.framecontainer);
    if (fragment == null) {
        ft.add(R.id.framecontainer, frag, tag);
    } else {
        ft.replace(R.id.framecontainer, frag, tag);
    }
    ft.addToBackStack(null);
    ft.commit();
```

I am confused because when I created my main activity, I called

```
setContentView(R.layout.baselayout);
```

This layout contained only a frame container, I would then add in a HomeScreenFragment right away and when I needed to change, I would use the `FragmentTransaction` code above.

However, if my new MapActivity used `setContentView(R.layout.maplayout);` how would I best change screens? If `R.id.maplayout` does not contain a framelayout, is it best to start a new activity that uses many fragments like the one I mentioned before? I remember hearing that calling `setContentView` more than once or outside `onCreate()` is bad practice.

It seems I am missing something because so far it seems like there is 2 ways of using activities with different layouts

1. Starting a new activity every time and just trying to minimize the amount of activities.
2. Make an activity with a FrameLayout and just swap fragments everytime

**To address my actual problem**
 I want my users to click another user marked on the map which will bring them to a `profilelayout` and view that user's profile, should I use one of the 2 methods above or how should I go about doing so?

Do you guys have any input to point me in the best direction? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If your current application is already fragment heavy, have you considered using [MapFragment](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/MapFragment)? I think if you're cleaning up your objects/resources appropriately it shouldn't really be a performance issue.

Also according to the documentation it says the following about the MapFragment:

> It's a wrapper around a view of a map to automatically handle the necessary life cycle needs.

I think it's also good to note that it's possible for you to do layout manipulation by adding/removing views using the LayoutInflater.